# React-Typescript - Dolby Interactive API

Tags: webrtc, react-typescript, dolby-audio-api

Could any one guide lines  how to implement dolby interactive API using react + typescript using webpack 5.

I'm trying to develop sample audio conference tool as part of project.

Below is the url for dolby

https://dolby.io/developers/interactivity-apis/reference/client-sdk/overview

Comment: Did you try UXKit Voxeet React as per [documentation](https://dolby.io/developers/interactivity-apis/reference/client-ux-kit/uxkit-voxeet-react) ?